# Request validation problem only for Googlebot

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, googlebot

I don't have a lot of hair, but I'm pulling out what little of it is left.

My MVC3 app serves images via Action like so

```
/Image/ShowImage/25-000252?t=a&o=1
```

a is predefined image size, o is image order for that item

Image is controller, ShowImage is action which returns FilePathResult. All this works without any problems except when Googlebot comes along. Then all of a sudden request validation kicks in

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
```

How and why are both beyond my ability to understand.

ShowImage action has ValidateInput(False), web.config has httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" but nothing seems to help.

Comment: @vnuk, What is the requested path for the request that fails? Are you sure it's like the example you posted? I'm asking because the obvious reason for the error is that the evil Googlebot actually does request a dangerous path. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. This only happens for Googlebot-Image/1.0, all other pages are crawled by Googlebot without any problems

Comment: @vnuk Strange. It sounds like Googlebot is escaping the ampersand or something, which would trigger this. I'm guessing you have trouble reproducing this error on-demand, otherwise you could try playing with the [allowed characters in the path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx).

Comment: I agree. I'll alter my image links to /Image/ShowImage/25-000252/?t=a&o=1 maybe that will change Googlebot's behaviour. But beyond that I'm pretty desperate...

Comment: @vnuk I still don't buy that the same path requested by a different client would sometimes cause errors. Are the IIS logs your source of this information? Is there nothing that differs between faulting and working requests besides the user agent?

Comment: This information of "offending" URL requested by Googlebot came from ELMAH. As far as I can tell, other crawlers (Yahoo) do not have this problem.

Comment: Adding / before & didn't help. Weirdest thing (so far) is that Googlebot successfully indexes everything on my site without tripping this exception. It seems that this exception happens only when it comes back to refresh(?) an image??

Comment: @Vnuk, is there some diagnostic information you could provide to us? Like how you log the error, how the error appears in the log, etc. This might help us think of other reasons for the error.

Comment: Entire ELMAH xml log for this error - http://pastebin.com/HLW7qPcq

Comment: @Vnuk, the URL according to this log is /Image/ShowImage/25-000176/?t=s&amp;o=1 - isn't it strange that the ampersand is URL query encoded but the question mark isn't? How exactly does the HTML look that is the link to this particular image?

Comment: This is XML log and to me it looks like pastebin isn't encoding it properly. Here is the same error from windows application log http://pastebin.com/HxpzFLbR there is nothing wrong with the link. I don't know how the HTML looks like beacuse googlebot provides no referrer (so I don't know where it got link from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2011/08/26/a-potentially-dangerous-request-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Turn on tracing for the app or install elmah or look in the logs for iis to see the path that is returning 500 status code. Then it should be clear what needs to change.

Comment: Didn't think of tracing, will give it a try.

Comment: doesn't elmah give you the url? If you want to work around this (I highly suggest you keep these built in protections on though) a solution is described to remove the invalid path chars at: http://www.christophercrooker.com/use-any-characters-you-want-in-your-urls-with-aspnet-4-and-iis    take note - this isn't just normal request validation. This is changing what characters are allowed in the path. Normal request validation also involves checks for ex. <X and will fail if < and another character are found. Your case is path specific, so there is a separate action you need (see url)

Comment: /Image/ShowImage/25-000252?t=a&o=1 is the URL (I stripped the http part) for now it looks like my change (added /) has done the trick. Haven seen "dangerous Request.Path" for 12h now, hope it stays this way :)

Comment: @Vnuk Still strange. :) I'd file a Connect bug if I were you. This reeks of hard-to-find-bug.